# Reference regarding classical treatment of spin

Tags: quantum-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, angular-momentum, quantum-spin, resource-recommendations

While going through [these notes](http://hitoshi.berkeley.edu/221A/spin.pdf) about spin, I encountered the classical Lagrangian for spin (section 2). But the treatment here is very concise and I can't seem to find any other resources treating spin in this same way. Does anybody know a place where this is treated in more detail?

Comment: Minor comment to the post (v2): Please consider to mention explicitly author, title, etc. of link, so it is possible to reconstruct link in case of link rot.